# EF Core ApplicationUser not able to .Include() one to many entity

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have my ASP.NET Core Identity `ApplicationUser` I inherited from `IdentityUser`, and gave it one `ICollection` of a model I call `Lockup`. I should be able to call `_context.ApplicationUser.Include(u => u.Lockups)`, but the `Lockup` is nowhere to be found for the `ApplicationUser`. I can call `_context.Lockup.ApplicationUser` just fine.

Here is the code for my two models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Lockup> Lockups { get; set; }
}


public class Lockup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }     
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [other properties...]

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

What simple thing am I missing about the relationship here? Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: are you getting any kind of error or just you cannot access it?

Comment: @Amir: No errors. Just can't get `.Include()` nor `Lockups` to display in Intellisense, See my updated screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing 'S' on ApplicationUsers? Otherwise, all seems good on your code.

```
_context.ApplicationUsers.Include(u => u.Lockups)
```

Comment: If missed `s` then `_context` should not found `ApplicationUser`

Comment: are you able to find _context.ApplicationUsers ? I mean not _context.Lockup.ApplicationUser

Comment: If not then how he tries to find `lockup`

Comment: It is the convention, right? On creating a new entity, its data set name will be plural

Comment: Yes! You are correct but may be he is using singular name.

Comment: I see your screenshot now and I can see that it is on plural _context.ApplicationUsers. If you are using code first approach it is up to you for the convention so is for Lockup entity but for the ApplicationUser it will be plural as you are using IdentityUser. That is what I was trying to clear. But you found the solution. Cheers ..

Answer (score 1):

Simple. I didn't have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in there. Didn't realize all my other LINQ queries weren't actually requiring EF. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Haha! By the way great to see that problem has been fixed!

Comment: That's why its always better to post the code with namespaces